# Spell targets player in multiplayer game, and that player leaves. Does it still resolve?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have infinite mana, [Soulfire Grand Master](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391927) and [Crater's Claws](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386509). I play a multiplayer game with 5 other players. I use [Soulfire Grand Master](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391927) last ability with infinite damage crater claws on first opponent. He doesn't wait until the spell resolve, and leave the game.

Will the spell resolve, so I can take it back to my hand and kill 4 other opponents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, the spell will be countered by the game rules.**

If all targets of a targeted spell or ability become illegal before resolution, the spell/ability will be countered and nothing that would happen on resolution will happen.

> 608.2b If the spell or ability specifies targets, it checks whether the targets are still legal. A target that’s no longer in the zone it was in when it was targeted is illegal. Other changes to the game state may cause a target to no longer be legal; for example, its characteristics may have changed or an effect may have changed the text of the spell. If the source of an ability has left the zone it was in, its last known information is used during this process. **The spell or ability is countered if all its targets, for every instance of the word “target,” are now illegal.** If the spell or ability is not countered, it will resolve normally. However, if any of its targets are illegal, the part of the spell or ability’s effect for which it is an illegal target can’t perform any actions on that target, make another object or player perform any actions on that target, or make that target perform any actions. If the spell or ability creates a continuous effect that affects game rules (see rule 613.10), that effect doesn’t apply to illegal targets. The effect may still determine information about illegal targets, though, and other parts of the effect for which those targets are not illegal may still affect them.

Comment: Sadly, but it seems like the right answer. Well, I knew MTG isn't balanced for multiplayer, but still.
If you are interested, why did I create such a question and what is workaround - http://deckstats.net/decks/17099/180888-infinite-mana-untap-draw/en

Comment: @desudesudesu The issue is self balancing. If you concede every time someone throws a 999999 damage fireball of doom at your face, very quickly you will find that nobody wants to play with you.

Comment: @Rainbolt it works differently in different comunities, actually. Our community loves gimmics and gimmicly counterplay. On my memory one guy conceded when lifelink creatures attacked him. :)

Comment: Only one that I ever really made someone angry with was conceding in response to Krosan Grip after he allowed my O-Ring trigger to exile his Commander. :)

Answer (score -2):

##Edit

No, it does not resolve. This is a valid technique, although it may be considered unsporting in casual play because it is essentially kingmaking.

[Source](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/MagicCompRules_20140926.txt)

`104.3a A player can concede the game at any time. A player who concedes leaves the game immediately. He or she loses the game.`

##Old, wrong answer

Yes, it resolves.

This is for the same reason that players cannot sacrifice a creature in response to your targeting it if they have no spell or ability that can make them do so.

If your opponent, on the other hand, casts [Lightning Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Bolt) on himself and reduces his life total to 0 *before* your spell resolves, it will be countered.

Comment: This is not true, you always have the right to concede and leave. Rule 102.3a: "A player can concede the game at any time. A player who concedes loses the game immediately."

Comment: @Fr33dan Can you provide link to official page for that specific rule? Never heard that one before.

Comment: I was looking at [this MTG salvation page](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Concede) however consulting the most recent [comprehensive rules](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/MagicCompRules_20140926.txt) the same rule is actually 104.3a now.

Comment: That rule appears to check out

Comment: It's in the first Golden Rule! *101.1. Whenever a card’s text directly contradicts these rules, the card takes precedence. The card overrides only the rule that applies to that specific situation. The only exception is that **a player can concede the game at any time** (see rule 104.3a).* You really really should know the Golden Rules. These are the key rules of Magic.

Comment: I would strongly disagree that it is "unsporting" technique to concede. It is an explicit right as per the official rules.

Comment: In the case of the example, the Infinite damage would have wiped out every player at the end of the phase. Dropping out at this point just saves the other player(s), which I don't think the rule is intended for.

Comment: The intention of the rule, as far as can be told from the outside, is to codify a behaviour that in practice cannot be prevented anyway: a player just packing up and leaving the table for whatever reason. You need a clear cut-off point to not leave the game in undefined state, and if you allow a game to continue for any length beyond the time of concession, where would you draw the line? Why not extend the game until the stack resolves, or until the turn ends? Having the player drop out immediately is the most consistent and sensible way, and that also means applying the rule to multiplayer.

Comment: I definitely agree with itcould; while dropping out in such a manner is certainly legal, it falls under "kingmaking", which is unsportsmanlike. A player shouldn't take an action that doesn't help him win just in order to change who else does win.

Comment: There could be an exception if it were a tournament, and you need the active player to lose this game if you want win the tournament. In that case quitting before dying would simply be the best strategy to winning the tournament.